# Where is this port being forwarded?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, tomcat

I'm working with a Tomcat application that I inherited.  The server has port 80 forwarding to 8080 to mask the default port.

When I type `iptables --list` I get

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

When I type `netstat -anp --tcp --udp` there is no reference to port 80

grepping through my /etc/init.d dir I can't find any relevant references to port 80.

This is all hosted on an ec2 - is it possible this is being forwarded at a higher level?

The reason I want to remove the current port forwarding is to move the application over to Varnish for both forwarding and caching

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat listens on 8080 by default, because it's assumed that apache will be running as well, and that'd cause all kinds of conflicts. [Here](http://www.klawitter.de/tomcat80.html) is a short tutorial on how to get it to run on 80.

Comment: Thanks but that's not quite what I'm looking for.  The port forwarding from 80 to 8080 is already in place; I just can't find anything that references how or why this is working

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

There is a rule written in /etc/rc.local to create a PREROUTING rewrite rule from port 80 to 8080

Since it was prerouting it didn't show up in by calling `iptables -L`, but it did with `iptables -t nat -L`